# Combining revert with jQuery draggable/droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, droppable

I'm using the drag and drop plugin with jQuery UI. I'd like to make it so that the draggable container can only be dragged and dropped on the container. In the demonstration:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#revert

It has 2 options. One is to revert when it drags to the container, the second is to revert when it isn't dragged to the container.

Is there a way to combine these two? I don't want to be able to drag the #draggable container anywhere where there isn't a #droppable container.

Comment: Pardon my confusion but how is that different from the second example?

Comment: I'd like the #draggable not be able to be dropped to a new position aside from the #droppable container. Here is an example: http://i.imgur.com/KTEW4.gif

Comment: I found the solution by adding `$('#draggable2').remove(); $('#draggable').draggable({ revert: true });`.

Comment: I was referring to the jQuery example that says "I revert when I'm **not** dropped". But if you've figured it out, all's well I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above, I found the solution by adding :

```
$('#draggable2').remove(); 
$('#draggable').draggable({ revert: true });
```